# Weird characters in RabbitMQ queue names created by ServiceStack

Tags: rabbitmq, servicestack

I'm trying to add some custom logic to messages in ServiceStack and RabbitMQ.

It seems that the queues created by ServiceStack have some illegible characters prepended to the queue name and that makes it hard to reference them by name. For example (link from the RabbitMQ admin tool):

http://localhost:15672/#/queues/%2F/%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8Emq%3ATestRequest.inq

Note the **%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E** prepended to the queue name. Although the queue  looks like **mq:TestRequest.inq** it seems to have a different name. I also checked on another machine and the behaviour is consistent. I also suspect routing keys are affected in the same manner.

However, if I manually create a queue like this (and as far as I can see, ServiceStack does it in a similar way):

```
RabbitMqServer mqServer = new RabbitMqServer(connectionString: hostName, username: userName, password: password);
RabbitMqMessageFactory factory = (RabbitMqMessageFactory)MqServer.MessageFactory;

using (var mqClient = new RabbitMqProducer(factory))
{
    var channel = mqClient.Channel;

    string qName = new QueueNames(typeof(TestRequest)).In;
    channel.QueueDeclare(qName, true, false, false, null);
}
```

The creted queue has a "normal" name without extra characters.
http://localhost:15672/#/queues/%2F/mq%3ATestRequest.inq

Also, it seems that the exchanges are created with names as expected.

My questions:

How to force ServiceStack to create queues without appending these characters?

OR

How to construct queue names containing these characters?

---

**EDIT:**

It seems that the inserted character is Left-to-right mark (**`&lrm;`** or **\u200e**). Prepending these characters to the queue name / routing key seems to get the job done. However, this looks rather hacky so I'd like to avoid doing this.

Comment: I'm not seeing any Queue Names created by ServiceStack's RabbitMqServer containing this prefix. Can you provide a stand-alone repro? (i.e. link to GitHub)

Comment: I found the problem in the end. We read the queue prefix from our web.config and that entry contained these characters and this naturally got propagated to RabbitMQ. But it was really hard to find since even the VS debugger doesn't show any special characters.

Answer (score 2):

This might be inside the internals of RabbitMQ and may depend if you are using AMQP or STOMP. Here is an except from the full page:

> If /, % or non-ascii bytes are in the queuename, exchange_name or routing_key, they are each replaced with the sequence %dd, where dd is the hexadecimal code for the byte.

[RabbitMQ - Stomp - Destinations - AMQP Semantics](https://www.rabbitmq.com/stomp.html)